# C# MongoDB AutoGenerateId without attributes

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public string someProperty { get; set;}
}
```

If you notice, the Id property it's an object type. This is very important because I don't wanna to have any MongoDb dependence on my Models, thus the same models will be used in others databases repositories.

So I have my FooMongoDBRepository where my class map are defined:

```
    public class FooMongoDBRepository : IFooRepository{

        public MongoDbSubscriberRepository (MongoDatabase database){
            BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(Foo));
            if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered (typeof(Foo))) {
                BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Foo> (cm => {
                    cm.AutoMap ();
                    cm.SetIdMember (cm.GetMemberMap (c => c.Id));
                });
            }

        }
     }
```

This work fine for inserts, but when try to Upsert, my _id key is always NULL. Can someone help me, how to force the Id field to be generated without using annotations ?

Thanks in advanced!

**Edit: Now It's working!, here is the code**

```
                cm.AutoMap ();
                cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id).SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
                cm.SetIdMember (cm.GetMemberMap (c => c.Id));
                cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(ObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
```

Comment: You added the SetIgnoreIfDefault() which is needed for upsert. Glad it works for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

`[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` to your **Id**

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.SomeProperty)
        .SetDefaultValue("abc")
        .SetIgnoreIfDefault(true);
});
```

The sample above can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#default-values)